# Sending all users push notification in ios

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to send push notification to all users who is installed my iOS app. Can you tell me the best and easy process for this?I want to send push without storing or using any specific device token. It will work for **all users**. I'm using FCM for this but for user segment i don't get push notification. For single device by given fcm token it's working fine.

Comment: Best way to implement FCM.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter

Comment: Refer https://www.raywenderlich.com/156966/push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send push notification manually to everyone who has your app installed already you should use Firebase cloud messaging.

You can read more here: https://firebase.google.com.

If you find this answer useful/correct, please mark it as correct.